# Cloud function, 2nd gen concurrency?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

They saying 2nd gen is

```
Concurrency: Process up to 1000 concurrent requests with a single function instance, 
minimizing cold starts and improving latency when scaling.
```

but as far as I know..

pre ver Cloud function`s maximum concurrent invocation of a single instance is 3000

so is it kinda downgrade??

Comment: Also does anyone know how this affects the onCall version of requests? and gen 2 firebase trigger functions? Can they also do concurrent requests? onCall has on concurrency option settings and the gen2 docs don't mention this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gen 1 functions can only handle [1 concurrent request](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#auto-scaling_and_concurrency) at a time per instance. This means that while your code is processing one request, there is no possibility of a second request being routed to the same instance.

Gen 2 functions on the other hand can handle up to 1000 concurrent requests *per function instance*.

Comment: Hi, I still don\`t get it can u explain more easily please?, Gen 1, in their docs, they saying 3000 concurrent request is fine https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

Comment: @hoapol the link you've shared refers to _invocation rate_ for background functions if you see the example. What the gen2 concurrency is referring to is that same instance can handle upto 1000 concurrent requests without request being routed to another instance.

Comment: hm that`s kinda difficult concept, need to study, thanks

Comment: The [Understanding Cloud Functions for Firebase Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM) might be helpful too. Essentially in gen 1 function instance can handle only 1 concurrent request at a time so if there's any new request it would be handled by any other instance that might lead to [cold starts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM) if there isn't any other instance.